# I am trying to down load the entire s3 bucket from aws using python but getting a OSError[error22]

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, data-science

I am trying to download the entire s3 bucket from aws using python. I used the following code to do it:

```
import os
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('mys3bucket')

for s3_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    path, filename = os.path.split(s3_object.key)
    my_bucket.download_file(s3_object.key, filename)
```

It is throwing the following error

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'PROFILEPIC_c3c1930d-94d9-4b7a-a3a4-6206e2349d3e2018-07-13 21:36:49.jpg.4C30370c'

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running this code?

you can try this using client -

`client_s3=boto3.client('s3')
res = client_s3.list_objects(Bucket=self.bucket_name)
for list_key in res['Contents']:
    client_s3.download_file(bucket_name, list_key, <dwonload location>)`

Comment: what if there are thousands of files in the bucket...will it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import boto3

#initiate s3 resource
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

# select bucket
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('my_bucket_name')

# download file into current directory
for s3_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    # Need to split s3_object.key into path and file name, else it will give error file not found.
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(s3_object.key)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(s3_object.key))
    path, filename = os.path.split(s3_object.key)
    my_bucket.download_file(s3_object.key, filename)
```